# PCA on returns: to scale or not to scale

Tags: r, pca

I am running PCA on time series data that has returns for a particular stock. Usually, when I run PCA for non-financial data I always scale the data with some R command like `prcomp(data,scale=TRUE)`. However, I believe that returns data is scaled to a certain level. So when using returns data should my command be `prcomp(returns,scale=False)`?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you're want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.